# Decrypt fields in VB.NET DataSet

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I have this working fine in a DataTable, however the DataSet does not have the **.Rows** property. All fields will not be encrypted, thus they will not all be decrypting. I am assuming it would be some kind of loop, like:

```
For (i = 0, i < DataSet.ColumnIndex [Or something], i++)
```

However, I am not sure how to perform this.

Essentially, when I bring back data using a SELECT queries based on input parameters the user enters (first name, last name) I would like to decrypt specific rows.

How I currently use it:

```
        Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(dt.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT"))
            dt.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(dt.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT"))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Either the first name or last name did not match. Please check your spelling.")
    End Try
```

The reason I need a DataSet is because I need to run reports off of this decrypted data. I have tried with my DataTable, however I have not been successful. From research, it seems as though DataSet is the common choice anyway.

Comment: Dataset doesn't hold data, DataTables do. Your real problem is that you haven't been able to generate your report from a DataTable. Expand on this please.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure. I create the DataTable through code. When I go to create a report [right click - add new item - report] the DataTable is not in the Report Data box on the left side of the screen. If I click the 'New' drop down, it's DataSet, Parameters, and Image. This is why I figured I needed to get the DataTable to a DataSet.

Comment: If I try to use a DataSet.TableAdapter, I get an error in the reportViewer: "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DataSet object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just a collection of DataTable objects

You can access the DataTables in a DataSet by:

Oridinal `Dim MyDataTable as DataTable = MyDataSet.Tables(2)` or

Name `Dim MyDataTable as DataTable = MyDataSet.Tables("Customers")`

So just use one of the above methods to decrypt the data once you have the DataSet

```
For i As Integer = 0 To MyDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
    MyDataTable.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(MyDataTable.Rows(i)("FIRST_NM_TXT"))
    MyDataTable.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT") = clsEncrypt.DecryptData(MyDataTable.Rows(i)("LAST_NM_TXT"))
Next
```

Comment: Okay, so I now have the DataTable with the Decrypted data in a DataSet ds. How do I get this in a report?

Comment: That's a different question

Comment: Woops, I thought I had asked that also. Sorry! Thanks for your help. I guess the only line I was really missing was the `=ds.Tables(#)`